# Location Service stop updates after a few kilometres

Tags: android

I have create android service to get location periodically which works fine for a few kilometres when the rider is in motion then it stop getting location update. I dont know what am doing wrong.
[here](https://pastebin.com/GVZBG6Yj) is my Fused Location class and here is [location service](https://pastebin.com/LKw2p8pE). There rider is using android version 9.0. But the same code if i try in my simulator route movement it works fine I got no idea what I could be missing.

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationService";
    private LocationManagerListener locationManagerListener;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e(TAG, "service started:");

    }

    void in_it_location()
    {
        locationManagerListener=new LocationManagerListener(this, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void locationResponse(Location location) {

                saveUserLocation(location);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand: called.");
        createNotification();
        in_it_location();
       if(locationManagerListener!=null)
           locationManagerListener.initLocation();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }


    private void saveUserLocation(final Location location){
        Log.e(TAG, "saveUserLocation: changed");
        Intent i = new Intent(LOCATION_ACQUIRED);
         i.putExtra("location",location);

         LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getBaseContext()).sendBroadcast(i);


    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
       if(locationManagerListener!=null)
            locationManagerListener.stopUpdateLocation();
    }


    private static final String NOTIFICATION_TITLE="Demo Title";
    private static final String NOTIFICATION_TEXT="Demo Body";
    private Context context;
    private void createNotification() {
        context= getBaseContext();

        Notification notification;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            OreoNotificationManager oreo = new OreoNotificationManager(context,false);
            Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Notification.Builder builder = oreo.getOreoNotification(MessageTemplate.MESSAGE_TITLE, NOTIFICATION_TEXT,
                    null,
                    defaultSound, R.drawable.bike_icon);
            notification=builder.build();

        }else{
            //Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.bike_icon)
                    .setContentTitle(NOTIFICATION_TITLE)
                    .setContentText(NOTIFICATION_TEXT)
                    .setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000 })
                    .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
                    //.setSound(defaultSound);
                    //.setContentIntent(getPendingIntent());
            notification=builder.build();
        }
         startForeground(123456789,notification);
    }
}
```